# Listing entity translated nodes

Tags: nodes, blocks, i18n-l10n

I've installed the entity translation module and everything is translated correctly, the only problem is that when I change the site language, translated nodes are not listed anymore in the main page content block. Nodes are only displayed when the chosen site language is the one in which the node was created.

Is there anyway to list entity translated nodes?

Comment: I thought that there was a global setting for this but I'm not at my laptop right now, but I know you can modify the view to not use the current language or you can modify to use current users language. This article should help point you in the right way: https://www.drupal.org/node/1327012 if there's not an answer by the time I get to my laptop I will provide more information

Comment: Thanks, views module really solved the problem. I've lost a lot of time searching for a way to do this with the "Main page content" block but I haven't found nothing useful.
For someone in the same situation, after creating the view, it's necessary to create a new page and set it as homepage so that the "Main page content" block doesn't display a message stating that there is no content.